# Create a unique ID based on the value in a row for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, reference, uniqueidentifier

I am in the process of creating a web application for a genealogy project.  I want each person I add onto the database to have a unique id, based on the first 3 characters of their surname (let's call it, for the purpose of explaining, 'surname-string'), concatenated with an autoincrement (which starts from 00001 for each unique 'surname-string').

For example - a person's surname is "Smith".  The surname-string will be SMI and due to the fact that they are the first surname-string "SMI" the full reference will be SMI00001.  Another person's surname is Black, making their surname-string BLA, and because they are the first one with the surname-string BLA, their reference will be BLA00001.  A third person's surname is also Smith - they are the second person with the SMI surname-string, so their reference should be SMI00002.

This unique id will be used in the persons URL, to be searched by and create relationships between people in the database.

I have no clue how to approach this logically.

I have not tried anything yet. It goes way over my head!

Comment: First step is to design an algorith to generate IDs the way you want. A flux diagram will help.

Comment: You haven't made a convincing argument for this method. If you cannot, simply use an [auto-increment column](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sequence/) in the person table of your database.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware my question is not about convincing someone if should I use it, I have specifics reasons why I need it.  I want to know how do I do it - thank you.

Comment: I simply offered the normal and easy solution almost everybody uses to create unique identifiers for rows in a database. I also said that you must have very good arguments to deviate from that. Clearly you have, but you don't want to share them. That's fine. I don't care.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you are misunderstanding me - my answer contains no animosity - I genuinely thought your answer was based on why do it rather than how to do it.   It makes referencing and searching for records much easier when you are looking at 5000+ records.

Comment: `I have not tried anything yet. It goes way over my head!` The solution is definitely not Stackoverflow.

Comment: OK, so it's for ease of manual searching? Why have a database, and then do manual searches? Let me make an argument against your unique identifiers: What if someone marries and ask you to change their surname in your database? Do you change the unique id as well?

Answer (score 1):

This method is sketchy, normally you should use auto-increment from database (numeric) or auto generate unique ID, for example md5(time().'randomsalt'.$username).

But if you have to use XXX00000 format you will need function to:

- check if there is BLA00001 in database
- if yes, check BLA00002 etc.
- if no, create new entry

This will be very slow after some time plus every name have maximum 99999 chances of existence, after that you need to change BLA to BL1, BL2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a before insert trigger.

Consider the following table, where `uniqu_identifier` is the unique identifier based on the surname:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
surname varchar(20),
uniqu_identifier varchar(30) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )   ;
```

You have to use a trigger because MySQL doesn't allow using the auto_increment column on a generated as column.

A trigger would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_BEFORE_INSERT
       BEFORE INSERT ON test 
       FOR EACH ROW
         BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE left(surname,3) = left(new.surname,3)) THEN
             SET new.uniqu_identifier = (select concat(upper(left(new.surname,3)),'0000' ,max(right(uniqu_identifier,1)) +1) from test  );
           ELSE 
              SET new.uniqu_identifier = concat(upper(left(new.surname,3)),'00001');
         END IF ;
    END
```

Some insert values

```
insert into test (surname) values ('SMITH');
insert into test (surname) values ('SMITH1');
insert into test (surname) values ('JOHN');

select * 
from test;
```

Result:

```
id  surname     uniqu_identifier
1     SMITH      SMI00001
2     SMITH1     SMI00002
3     JOHN       JOH00001
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Wc58Ne_j

Comment: This is a clever solution, but it doesn't do what is asked. It's the first JOHN in your database, yet he gets the number 2.

Comment: Yes, this works, but it now updates every row in the table on every insert. That's not very efficient, and it starts to get rather complex too. Perhaps the initial idea of this type of "unique identifier" is not very practical?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it updates every new row and yes it is complex. I would rather choose a unique key on first_name, last_name and not storing at all the `uniqu_identifier`  but use  a select statement to generate it .  I will let the answer be for the OP and anyone who  might find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Hy
On Create Table you can make the default value of UID like this :

Create Table 'Users'
(ID...
UID varchar(100) Default (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Firstname, 1, 3), LPAD(ID, 8, '0')))

Substring to return the first 3 char of the username
LPAD to convert the int to 8 digits (ex : 1 => 00000001)